# in spring boot Junit 5 how mocking catch external call and customize response

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5, wiremock

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ApplicationIntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort;
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @ClassRule
    private static WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().dynamicPort());


    @BeforeAll
    void init() throws IOException {
        wireMockServer.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    void tearDown() throws IOException {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }

    @Test
    void SearchShelf() throws Exception {
        wireMockServer.configureFor("1.2.3.4", 1111);
        this.wireMockServer.stubFor(WireMock.get(urlEqualTo("https://1.2.3.4:1111/aaa/unit"))
                                            .withQueryParam("name", equalTo("ABCD"))
                                            .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)
                                                                   .withBody("[]")));

        this.webTestClient.get()
                          .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/unitmgmt/unit")
                                                       .queryParam("name", "ABCD")
                                                       .build())
                          .exchange()
                          .expectStatus()
                          .is2xxSuccessful();
    }
```

In my Microservice after controller receive a call, in another layer it will sent request using restTemplate to an third party api, I want to mock that external api(catch "https://1.2.3.4:1111/aaa/unit", then return customize response). But now, it is just not stub any request that restempate sent, the response I get seems like "wireMockServer.stubFor" is not work, or is there another frame can help me to achieve that goal? If anyone can help me, I will be much appreciate.

I tried manually binding server host and port to the external api before restart mockserver but it will not compile.

```
private static WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().bindAddress("1.2.3.4").port(1111))
```

Also I tried MockServer frame, that has same issue.

What I excepting:

in integration test: when I sent a http request to the server, it will catch the one last connector's url call which goes to the external api, then return customize response for acceptance test purpose.

Comment: You can bind the WireMock server to local IP address only. Defaults to the loopback adaptor. To achieve what you want you would need to configure your underlining web client to use `localhost` instead and wiremock port.